# Lightbox2 div tag aligning left despite center aligning

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, lightbox2

I am using Dreamweaver CS5 to design a website. I have downloaded [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and have integrated it into the site. All works fine, apart from the fact that the thumbnails are always left aligned no matter what I do. I am using the following code to achieve the Lightbox functionality:

```
<div class="imageRow">                     
<div class="single">
      <div align="center">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="images/Milkshake2.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/Milkshake2.png" alt="" width="177" height="113" /></a></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This produces the following:

[image: left-aligned]

However, If I remove the imageRow div tag, I get the following:

[image: Center Aligned]

Which leads me to believe that the problem lies within the imageRow code. Here is the CSS file:

```
 /* Lightbox v2 Project page styles 
 *  Author: Lokesh Dhakar http://www.lokeshdhakar.com
 *  Created: a long time ago (2006 I think)
 *  Table of Contents:
 *      layout
 *      typography
 *    content */
/* line 17, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* line 20, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
body {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 22, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 24, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 26, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* line 28, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
/* line 101, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

/* line 30, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
a img {
  border: none;
}

/* line 114, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/* layout
 *----------------------------------------------- */
/* line 18, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

/* line 24, ../sass/screen.sass */
#content {
  margin: 0 40px 40px 280px;
}

/* line 27, ../sass/screen.sass */
.row {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/* line 38, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Typography
 *----------------------------------------------- */
/* line 33, ../sass/screen.sass */
body {
  background: #222222 url(../images/bg-checker.png);
}

/* line 36, ../sass/screen.sass */
body, input, textarea {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.625em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* line 45, ../sass/screen.sass */
#lightbox {
  text-shadow: none;
}

/* line 48, ../sass/screen.sass */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Fredoka One", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  line-height: 1.625em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #d0eb6a;
}

/* line 56, ../sass/screen.sass */
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

/* line 60, ../sass/screen.sass */
h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 1.45em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

/* line 65, ../sass/screen.sass */
h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #88a616;
}

/* line 71, ../sass/screen.sass */
h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Text elements */
/* line 77, ../sass/screen.sass */
p {
  margin: 0 0 1.25em 0;
  line-height: 1.625em;
}

/* line 81, ../sass/screen.sass */
ul, ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.25em 0;
}

/* line 84, ../sass/screen.sass */
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* line 87, ../sass/screen.sass */
dd {
  margin-bottom: 1.625em;
}

/* line 90, ../sass/screen.sass */
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* line 93, ../sass/screen.sass */
i {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* line 96, ../sass/screen.sass */
pre {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #e7931a;
  font: 14px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
}

/* line 107, ../sass/screen.sass */
code, kbd {
  font: 14px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 2px 6px 2px black;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #e7931a;
}

/* line 115, ../sass/screen.sass */
pre code {
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Links */
/* line 122, ../sass/screen.sass */
a {
  color: #8ad459;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* line 125, ../sass/screen.sass */
a:hover {
  color: #589e29;
}

/* line 128, ../sass/screen.sass */
::-moz-selection,
::selection {
  background: #e7931a;
  color: white;
}

/* sidebar
 *----------------------------------------------- */
/* line 137, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
/* line 140, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
/* line 142, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar a {
  color: white;
}
/* line 144, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .logo {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 146, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .logo em {
  color: #8ad459;
}
/* line 148, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .logo:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #d0eb6a, 0 0 50px #d0eb6a;
}
/* line 150, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .author {
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
/* line 154, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .author a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
/* line 156, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .author .twitter {
  font-size: 14px;
}
/* line 158, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .author .twitter a {
  color: #4d9ed8;
}
/* line 160, ../sass/screen.sass */
#sidebar .author .twitter em {
  color: #4d9ed8;
}

/* line 163, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1.5em 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
}
/* line 170, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* line 173, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0.6em 0.2em 0.3em 20px;
  background: #505050;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 181, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-color: #88a616;
}
/* line 184, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav a.first {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
/* line 188, ../sass/screen.sass */
#nav a.last {
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* content
 *----------------------------------------------- */
/* line 196, ../sass/screen.sass */
.download {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 40px 40px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 204, ../sass/screen.sass */
.download:hover {
  border-color: #8ad459;
  background-color: #444444;
}
/* line 207, ../sass/screen.sass */
.download .box {
  float: left;
}
/* line 209, ../sass/screen.sass */
.download .file {
  float: left;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
/* line 216, ../sass/screen.sass */
.download .file .version {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #8ad459;
}

/* line 221, ../sass/screen.sass */
.filelist {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
/* line 226, ../sass/screen.sass */
.filelist .header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* line 229, ../sass/screen.sass */
.filelist .folder {
  color: #999999;
}
/* line 231, ../sass/screen.sass */
.filelist .note {
  color: #999999;
}

/* line 235, ../sass/screen.sass */
.changelog {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
/* line 237, ../sass/screen.sass */
.changelog li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 14px;
  background: url(../images/bullet.gif) no-repeat 0 11px;
  color: #999999;
}
/* line 242, ../sass/screen.sass */
.changelog li .version {
  color: #88a616;
}
/* line 244, ../sass/screen.sass */
.changelog li .date {
  color: white;
}
/* line 246, ../sass/screen.sass */
.changelog .old {
  display: none;
}

/* line 249, ../sass/screen.sass */
.showOlderChanges {
  color: #999999;
}

/* line 253, ../sass/screen.sass */
.forums {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 40px 40px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 261, ../sass/screen.sass */
.forums:hover {
  border-color: #8ad459;
  background-color: #444444;
}
/* line 264, ../sass/screen.sass */
.forums .speech {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
/* line 267, ../sass/screen.sass */
.forums .link {
  float: left;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
/* line 274, ../sass/screen.sass */
.forums .link .sub {
  color: #8ad459;
}

/* line 278, ../sass/screen.sass */
#elsewhere .button {
  font-family: "Fredoka One", "lucida grande", tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 20px 40px 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  color: white;
}
/* line 291, ../sass/screen.sass */
#elsewhere .button:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
  border-color: #8ad459;
}

/* misc
 *----------------------------------------------- */
/* line 298, ../sass/screen.sass */
p.lead {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* line 305, ../sass/screen.sass */
hr {
  height: 6px;
  background: #3d3d33;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  clear: both;
}

/* line 312, ../sass/screen.sass */
.section {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
/* line 314, ../sass/screen.sass */
.section:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

/* line 317, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow {
  *zoom: 1;
  margin: 20px 0;
  float: right;
}
/* line 38, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss */
.imageRow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* line 320, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .single {
  float: right;
}
/* line 322, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .single a {
  float: inherit;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-right: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 332, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .single a img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/* line 335, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .single a:hover {
  background-color: #8ad459;
}
/* line 337, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set {
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* line 343, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
/* line 346, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set .single a {
  background: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-right: 0;
}
/* line 351, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set .single a:hover {
  background-color: #8ad459;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* line 355, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set .single.first a {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
/* line 358, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow .set .single.last a {
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  /* line 364, ../sass/screen.sass */
  body, input, textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  /* line 367, ../sass/screen.sass */
  body {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  /* line 370, ../sass/screen.sass */
  .section {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }

  /* line 373, ../sass/screen.sass */
  p.lead {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  /* line 376, ../sass/screen.sass */
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  /* line 379, ../sass/screen.sass */
  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  /* line 382, ../sass/screen.sass */
  h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  /* line 385, ../sass/screen.sass */
  code, kbd {
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  /* line 388, ../sass/screen.sass */
  pre code {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  /* line 391, ../sass/screen.sass */
  pre {
    padding: 0.75em;
  }

  /* line 394, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar {
    width: 160px;
    left: 20px;
  }

  /* line 398, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #content {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  /* line 403, ../sass/screen.sass */
  body, input, textarea {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  /* line 407, ../sass/screen.sass */
  p.lead {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  /* line 410, ../sass/screen.sass */
  code, kbd {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  /* line 413, ../sass/screen.sass */
  pre code {
    font-size: 11px;
  }

  /* line 416, ../sass/screen.sass */
  pre {
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  /* line 420, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #3d3d33;
  }
  /* line 427, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  /* line 429, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar .twitter {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  /* line 431, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar #nav {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  /* line 433, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar #nav li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  /* line 435, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #sidebar #nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }

  /* line 441, ../sass/screen.sass */
  h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  /* line 444, ../sass/screen.sass */
  h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  /* line 447, ../sass/screen.sass */
  #content {
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
  }

  /* line 450, ../sass/screen.sass */
  .download {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* line 456, ../sass/screen.sass */
  .download .box, .download .file {
    float: none;
  }

  /* line 459, ../sass/screen.sass */
  .forums {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* line 465, ../sass/screen.sass */
  .forums .speech, .forums .link {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Can Anyone see a problem here?

Comment: where is your code ?? or the problem is the plugin itself ? i cant see the problem in plugin

Comment: The image is centred when I remove the imageRow div tag. So I presumed the problem would lie in the code which I placed above.

Comment: can you upload your code on test server

Comment: so that i can check what is the exact problem as i am not able to find your problem yet :-)

Comment: Sorry, the site isn't live yet and I am unable to release the domain name. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: so can you add detailed screenshot ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16033/discussion-between-alex-godbehere-and-sachin)

Answer (score 0):

properties for `.imageRow` start with the basic bloc :

```
/* line 317, ../sass/screen.sass */
.imageRow {
  *zoom: 1;
  margin: 20px 0;
  float: right;
}
```

As you can see, this class manipulates margin and floating options. Other properties for the `.imageRow` class follow in the CSS file, try to manipulate those margins, displays and positions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm a novice when it comes to web design / CSS. How do you recommend I tweak it?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials available throughout the Internet on how to design a website and how to build it. The most common way seems to design the website in the first time (with Gimp, Photoshop or anything else) then reproduce the design with (mostly) divs and CSS styling. Ask Google for those.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how that helps me here. I understand the basics of divs (I have lots in my site), however this one is being a pain. I was merely wondering if anyone could see a problem with the code provided with lightbox2 which is causing my problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I thought you were speaking in general. As I said, this plugin clearly makes changes upon margins and paddings and this is the heart of your problem, especially with this class, since when you remove it the problem vanishes. If the lightbox's div is contained in other divs, don't forget to check if their properties don't interfere with those of the lightbox plugin.